# Angular - ngx clipboard throwing error when used for two elements in a same component

Tags: angular, ngx-clipboard

In my template, I have two form controls with copy to clipboard buttons

The error I'm facing:
Click on the second copy button and then
Cancel or save the form throws error.
[Error in the dev tool console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzKsa.png).

```
<div *ngIf="deployment.id">
<input slot="input" name="id" formControlName="id" type="text" class="form-control disabled" />

<div #depkeyContainer class="copyToClipboard">
    <button
        type="button"
        ngxClipboard
        [cbContent]="deployment.id"
        (cbOnSuccess)="isCopiedDepKey=true; copyToClipboardText();"
        [container]="depkeyContainer">
        Copy to clipboard
    </button>
</div>
</div>                    
<div *ngIf="deployment.snippet">
<textarea
        type="text"
        id="snippet"
        rows="9"
        formControlName="snippet"
        class="form-control disabled">
</textarea>
   
<div #snippetContainer class="copyToClipboard">
    <button
        type="button"
        ngxClipboard
        [cbContent]="deployment.snippet"
        (cbOnSuccess)="isCopiedSnippet=true; copyToClipboardText()"
        [container]="snippetContainer">
        Copy to clipboard
    <button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Noticed that the error is produced from the 'destroy' method of ngx-clipboard.js.

Comment: destroy(container = this.document.body) {
        if (this.tempTextArea) {
            container.removeChild(this.tempTextArea);
            // removeChild doesn't remove the reference from memory
            this.tempTextArea = undefined;
        }
    }

Comment: Here 'container' always holds reference to first clipboard div element.

Comment: Removing [container] property fixed the issue. Now the container holds the reference to document body element.